# Xcode 6.1 SourceKitServiceCrashed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I opened an app I've been working on and suddenly I'm getting this error message almost every line of code I type. Xcode is becoming unusable.

[image]

Whats is causing this and how do I fix it?